# Move cloth around moving object

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation, hard-ops

I have a plastic-like material that acts as a dust cover for a robot hand. I need the cover to deform around the base of the hand's thumb. Currently I have a subdivided plane with a cloud texture to simulate wrinkles. How can I make this cloth material wrap around and deform as the thumb moves?
[image: Hand thumb with fabric cover]

[image: How to make the fabric attach to and move with the base of the thumb]

The goal is to get the orange cloth to wrap around the base of the thumb and move/deform as it moves.